# How to arrange nodes in a circular pattern in Vis.js / D3.js

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, vis.js, vis.js-network

I went through the documentation and saw the examples given, but couldn't find anything related to the pattern that I want to display. Can anyone help me out how to make such network diagram in **Vis.js** or **D3.js**?
[image]
Basically I am working on an Angular project, after exploring a lot on google, reached to the conclusion of using Vis for the same. I need to make an interactive network diagram, where I can add delete nodes, select a particular node based on some actions performed. Please help me out, am I choosing the right library and
If not, what would be the better option?
If yes, then how can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: you could see [this example](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/static/jsfiddle.b15ea0216ef71667b637c36fe50c7b639c4cf59885116d4497afcd3b86e5639a.html) on how to make the circular arrangement.